# When is 'to' prepositional and when particle of infinitive?

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive

1.Having been in that kind of situation I can tell you it's not the good place **to be**.

2.Having been in that kind of situation I can tell you it's not the good place **to being**.

3.Having been in that kind of situation I can tell you it's not the good place **for working**.

Second sentence looks akward but when I change *to being* to *for working* as in third sentence it makes sense. How to know that *to* is part of an infinitive or a preposition? Transitive verbs can take to-infinitive as an object but that's not the case here. Please explain

Comment: S.N: For some reason, I would use a indefinite article prior to "good". Second one is not grammatically correct though. The preposition "**to**" has its own idiomatic usage, which is not the case in this context.

Comment: _For working_ is prepositional phrase; _to be_ is an infinitive. They are not the same thing at all, and you can't change one into another.

Comment: @John Lawler can you explain it I know it's a prepositional phrase but my question was different.

Comment: Any _to_ that comes before an infinitive verb form (which might look exactly like a noun -- though _be_ is always an only an infinitive) is an infinitive marker. The tricky part to determine what the verbs are.

Comment: @John Lawler and how to know when to use to-infinitive and prepositional phrase. Why my second sentence is wrong? If I say  Having been in that kind of situation I can tell you it's not the good place **for being**.  Like for example why we say I'm happy **to be** here and not I'm happy **being** here  or for **being here**

Comment: The use of prepositions and complementizers and articles and other little words with almost no meaning is determined by the meaningful words in the sentence -- the nouns, verbs, and adjectives -- and by the constructions and idioms they are used in. Therefore there is no rule for _to_ or _for_ or _the_ or other little words; instead there are rules for every noun, verb, and adjective in every construction. _Like_ can take a _to_-infinitive or a gerund complement, for instance, but _stop_ can take only a gerund.

Comment: @John Lawler 'I Stop **eating junk food**' 'I stopped **to eat something**'  You said there are rules for every noun, verb, adjective in every construction, so how can I learn them I mean how to determine that What I'm saying is idiomatic like if I say my sentence no.2 then someone can argue it's not idiomatic but grammatical correct.